# Why to use "Web Service or WCF" because Data Access/business Logic Layer already exist in our application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

As as my understanding use **Window Service** should come in place when some automatic process should be done on the basis of **Scheduling.**

Why should we use Web Service or WCF because already have **Data Access/Business Logic Layer** in our application. Also I think, for scheduling purposes Window Service is the good option.

Your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why should we use Web Service or WCF because already have Data
>   Access/Business Logic Layer in our application.

Because by exposing this functionality in a reusable service, other applications/platforms might take advantage of it. Of course if your DAL/BL is only used within a single application, you get no benefit from moving it into a separate service.

Comment: I could not understand it when you said **"you get no benefit from moving it into a separate service."**. Why so it is the case? because it is a dll and that can be reused. right ? can you kindly take out some time to explain or if possible to provide an example

Comment: What if the other application is written in Java? Or PHP? The DLL that you currently have will be of very little use. But if all your applications are written on .NET you could of course reuse this assembly. There's one thing you should be aware of though: if you need to make a change in this DLL you will have to recompile ALL the applications that are using it. Whereas if you expose the functionality in a service you will only have to modify the service without ever touching at consuming applications. So as you can see there are benefits, but it would really depend on your exact scenario.

Comment: As I've mentioned in my post it is also useful when you need interoperability across various systems.